# Using fmincon for optimizing nonlinear parameters of objective function

Tags: matlab, optimization

Suppose I have an objective function `f( Cs, As, ns, Xdat )` where `Cs` are linear parameters, `As` are non-linear parameters, `ns` are integer (non-linear) parameters, and `Xdat` is input data. Something like

```
function [ cval ] = f(Cs, As, ns, Xdat)
    n = length(Cs);
    cval = 0.0;
    for i = 1:n
        C = Cs(i);
        A = As(i);
        n = ns(i);
        for j = 1:length(Xdat)
            x = Xdat(j);
            cval = cval + C*(x^n)*exp(-A*x);
        end
    end
end
```

I want to optimize `Cs` and `As` (while holding `ns` constant) but I also want to use the constraint `sum(Cs) = 1.0`. How can I achieve these using `fmincon`?

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html), I do not see how to add parameters into the objective function which I do not wish to optimize (`ns`) and it is not immediately clear how to constrain `sum(Cs) = 1.0`.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) does explain how to pass extra parameters, and via parameters `Aeq` and `beq`, `fmincon` also provides a way to implement your constraint. If this doesn't help, please add information on what the possible values of the parameters of `f` are, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Btw., your code looks like it could be easily vectorized. Have you familiarized yourself with standard Matlab programming techniques? There's not much sense in programming Matlab as if it were C.